# How to pass parameter form rake file to model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have have a rake task .

and this is my code on it

i have a method called **terminate_conference(args)**

```
  task :terminate_conference, [ :unique ] => :environment do |t, args|
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      begin
        abort "no unique" unless args[:unique]
        rake.str << " -> #{args[:unique]}"
         rake.str << " -> #{args} -> KINGKANGKUNGKANGKING"
        unique_conference = Unique.new
        unique_conference.terminate_conference(args)
      rescue Exception => e
        ActiveRecord::Rollback
        logger.info "Error Terminating"
      end
    end
  end
```

and this is my model which has the function of **terminate_conference(params)**:

```
  def terminate_conference(params) # params must be an Hash object

    conditions = Hash.new
    conditions[:id] = params[:id] unless !params.has_key? :id
    conditions[:unique_number] = params[:unique_number] unless !params.has_key? :unique_number

    @unique = Unique.where(conditions).take
    if @unique
    confbridge = Confbridge.where( confno: @unique.unique_number)
    unique = Unique.where( unique_number: @unique.unique_number)
    confbridge.destroy_all
    unique.destroy_all


      circle = Circle.find(@unique.circle)
      circle[:conference2_total_channels] -= 5
      circle.save!
    end
  end
```

for example the value of **terminate_conference(12345)**

how can i get to my model? **terminate_conference(params)**

Comment: Please get rid of all unrelated code and post the question stating the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

`rake` commands load your entire application, so you should be able to access your model by simply calling `MyModel`.